# Как получить список меток из кластера yandex map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, яндекс-карты, cluster

Не могу понять, как получить из кластера данные, которые в нём находятся, чтобы потом их использовать в другом блоке. Пробую получить через mouseenter, но не могу найти нужные данные в объекте.

```
<Clusterer
                  onMouseEnter={(e: any) => {
                      return clusterHint(e)
                  }}
                  onMouseLeave={(e: any) => {
                      return clusterHintClose(e)
                  }}
                  options={{
                      clusterIconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
                      iconImageHref: '/images/map-icon.png',
                      iconImageSize: [64, 64],
                      iconImageOffset: [-32, -32],
                      iconContentOffset: [20, 20],
                      clusterIconContentLayout: cluster.layout,
                      gridSize: 256,
                      zoomMargin: 64
                  }}
              >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно получить при наведение на кластер значения с помощью

```
e.get('target').properties.get('geoObjects'));
```